# Nested calls to integral and integral2 in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nested

I have some code here which illustrates the nested nature of some integrals that I want to perform in matlab. When I run the following code I get the error

```
Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in fun1/integrand (line 7)
   f = x.^2.*t;
```

it seems that the way I have set it up now does not allow for vectorized output of the `integral` function. What can I do to make my code run? I have commented below what I want the functions to do.

My code is as follows:

%Main script:

```
z = linspace(0,10,10);
I = zeros(10,1);

for i = 1:10
    I(i) = fun2(z(i));
end
```

%Function 1 in separate file:

```
function I = fun1(x)

I = integral(@integrand,-1,1);

   function f = integrand(t)
   f = x.^2.*t;
   end
end
```

%Function 2 in separate file:

```
function I = fun2(z)

I = integral2(@integrand,-1,1,-1,1);

   function f = integrand(x,y)
       f = z.*fun1(x).*y;    // here fun1 should return the value for all x that is swept through by integral2 during its call.
   end
end
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your error message. You are only using `.*` so you won't get an error message `Error using  * `. Please verify you copied the right code and error message.

Comment: Sorry, edited now. There was a slight mistake, but now all my operations should by element wise ones.

Comment: Please check it again. "Inner matrix dimensions must agree." is not an exception which can be caused by `.*`

Comment: Sorry you are right I didn't copy the entire error message. It should be as I see it on my matlab prompt now!

Comment: I am trying to understand what you want to implement. Is this the formula you tried to implement? http://bit.ly/18B5itX Then you should use `integral3`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I realise I could use `integral3` here but I was wondering if my approach can be made to work, as it would simplify things a great deal for me (in my real problem)

Comment: Is this the formula you are trying to implement?

Comment: Yes, but this is just a simple example, ideally I want to use a separate integration routine on the innermost integral which is more efficient (it will be an FFT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are using `integral2` and `integral1` in a combination. This way `integral2` generates a grid for `x` and `y` and `integral1` generates the `t` values. This way the `t` and `x` values don't match in size, and even if they would they are part of a different grid.

As already discussed, using `ingetral3` is the right choice. Alternatively you could simply "fix" this introducing a loop, but this results in much slower code:

```
function I = fun1(x)
I=nan(size(x));
for ix=1:numel(x)
    I(ix) = integral(@(t)integrand(x(ix),t),-1,1);
end
   function f = integrand(x,t)
   f = x.^2.*t;
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I guess that is the only option!